# Apex trigger Not populating values on lookup field

Tags: apex, trigger, master-detail, cross-object

I have trigger which updates the few master record fields based on the values of the child record. IT_Asset_Management__c is the master object and Employee__c is the detail object.

The following is the trigger i wrote:

```
trigger EmployeeTrigger on Employee__c (after insert, after update) {

    List<Employee__c> employeeList = new List<Employee__c>();
    Map<Id, IT_Asset_Management__c> assetUpdateMap = new Map<Id, IT_Asset_Management__c>();

    if(!UtilConstants.RECURSIVE_EMPLOYEE_FLAG){
        if(Trigger.isAfter){
            Set<Id> assetIdSet = new Set<Id>();
            boolean provisionedFlag = false;
            for(Employee__c emp : Trigger.new){
                assetIdSet.add(emp.Assigned_Asset_ID__c);
            }

            Map<Id, IT_Asset_Management__c> assetMap = new Map<Id, IT_Asset_Management__c>(
                                                       [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, 
                                                                           Provisioned__c,
                                                                           Return_Date__c,
                                                                           Issue_Date__c,
                                                                           Assigned_To__c,
                                                                           Assigned_Asset_ID__c   
                                                                    FROM Employees__r 
                                                                    ORDER BY Issue_Date__c) 
                                                        FROM IT_Asset_Management__c 
                                                        WHERE Id IN: assetIdSet]);

            for(Employee__c  employee : Trigger.new){

                if(assetMap != null && assetMap.containsKey(employee.Assigned_Asset_ID__c) && 
                                       assetMap.get(employee.Assigned_Asset_ID__c).Employees__r != null){
                   for(Employee__c emp : assetMap.get(employee.Assigned_Asset_ID__c).Employees__r){
                      assetUpdateMap.put(emp.Assigned_Asset_ID__c, new IT_Asset_Management__c());
                      emp.Provisioned__c = false; 
                      if(emp.Return_Date__c != null){
                         if(emp.Issue_Date__c != null && emp.Issue_Date__c <= date.today() && emp.Return_Date__c <= date.today()){
                            emp.Provisioned__c = false;
                            if(assetUpdateMap.containsKey(emp.Assigned_Asset_ID__c))
                               assetUpdateMap.put(emp.Assigned_Asset_ID__c, new IT_Asset_Management__c(Id = emp.Assigned_Asset_ID__c, Assigned_To__c = null, Assign_Date__c = null, Status__c = 'Available'));
                         }else if(emp.Issue_Date__c != null && emp.Issue_Date__c <= date.today() && emp.Return_Date__c > date.today()){
                            if(provisionedFlag == false){
                               emp.Provisioned__c = true;  
                               provisionedFlag = true; 
                               assetUpdateMap.put(emp.Assigned_Asset_ID__c, new IT_Asset_Management__c(Id = emp.Assigned_Asset_ID__c, **Assigned_To__c = emp.Assigned_To__c**, Assign_Date__c = emp.Issue_Date__c, Status__c = 'Provisioned')); 
                            }else{
                               employee.addError('An Employee is currently using this asset. Please take the Asset back from the Existing Employee and then Assign to a New user');                              
                            }
                         }else if(emp.Issue_Date__c != null && emp.Issue_Date__c >= date.today() && emp.Return_Date__c >= date.today()){
                               emp.Provisioned__c = false; 
                               assetUpdateMap.put(emp.Assigned_Asset_ID__c, new IT_Asset_Management__c(Id = emp.Assigned_Asset_ID__c, Assigned_To__c = null, Assign_Date__c = null, Status__c = null));
                         }
                      }else{
                         if(emp.Issue_Date__c != null && emp.Issue_Date__c <= date.today() && provisionedFlag == false){
                            emp.Provisioned__c = true;  
                            provisionedFlag = true; 
                            assetUpdateMap.put(emp.Assigned_Asset_ID__c, new IT_Asset_Management__c(Id = emp.Assigned_Asset_ID__c, Assigned_To__c = emp.Assigned_To__c, Assign_Date__c = emp.Issue_Date__c, Status__c = 'Provisioned'));
                         }else if(emp.Issue_Date__c != null && emp.Issue_Date__c > date.today()){
                            emp.Provisioned__c = false;
                            assetUpdateMap.put(emp.Assigned_Asset_ID__c, new IT_Asset_Management__c(Id = emp.Assigned_Asset_ID__c, Assigned_To__c = null, Assign_Date__c = null, Status__c = null));
                         }else{
                            employee.addError('An Employee is currently using this asset. Please take the Asset back from the Existing Employee and then Assign to a New user'); 
                         }
                      }    
                      employeeList.add(emp);
                   }
                }
            }
            UtilConstants.RECURSIVE_EMPLOYEE_FLAG = true;
            update employeeList;     
            if(assetUpdateMap.size() > 0)
               update assetUpdateMap.values();                                     
        } 
    }           
}
```

So whenever this trigger is triggered, the Status, Assign Date on the master record is updated based on the changed made on the detail record. But the Assigned_To__c (which is a lookup field) is not updating the values from the detail record.

What do i have to do to make sure that the lookup field is also populating the value from its detail record?

Any suggestions?

Thank you.